# How To Store Values in Hashmap (comma Separated) with Same Key using Java Stream API?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a object named EntityObjectDTO like below:

```
 public @Data class EntityObjectDTO  {
     @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
     @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
     @Data
     public static class Attributes {

         private String name;

         private AttributeType attributeType;

         private String dataType;

     }
}
```

This AttributeType is an enum and can have values (RAW,REFERRED,ORIGINAL).
I am trying to store all the attributes names and dataType into Hashmap of String key and value.
This DataType can be duplicate as well. 
**Input:**

```
    EntityObjectDTO  obj= new EntityObjectDTO ();
    obj.getAttributes().setName("name1");
    obj.getAttributes().setAttributeType(REFERRED);
    obj.getAttributes().setDataType("Vehicle");

    obj.getAttributes().setName("name2");
    obj.getAttributes().setAttributeType(REFERRED);
    obj.getAttributes().setDataType("Vehicle");

    obj.getAttributes().setName("name3");
    obj.getAttributes().setAttributeType(REFERRED);
    obj.getAttributes().setDataType("Person");
```

**Expected in a HashMap:**

{"Vehicle","name1,name2"} 
 {"Person","name3"}

**This is what I tried:**

```
      Map<String, String> myMap = obj.getAttributes().stream()
            .filter(entity -> AttributeType.REFERRED.equals(entity.getAttributeType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(EntityObjectDTO.Attributes::getDataType, e -> e.getName()));<br/>
```

But by this I am getting : **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message : Duplicate key Vehicle (attempted merging values name1 and name2)**

How do I achieve the expected output by doing some modifications in existing code?

Comment: Change your last line as `.collect(Collectors.toMap(EntityObjectDTO.Attributes::getDataType, e -> e.getName(),(s1,s2) -> String.join(",",s1,s2)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `EntityObjectDTO` as below,

```
public class EntityObjectDTO {

    private Attributes attributes;

    public Attributes getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Attributes attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

and `Attributes` as below,

```
public class Attributes {
    private String name;
    private String dataType;
    private AttributeType attributeType;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }

    public void setDataType(String dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public AttributeType getAttributeType() {
        return attributeType;
    }

    public void setAttributeType(AttributeType attributeType) {
        this.attributeType = attributeType;
    }
}
```

Then the below is fine to you,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            EntityObjectDTO obj= new EntityObjectDTO ();

            Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
            attributes.setName("name1");
            attributes.setDataType("Vehicle");
            attributes.setAttributeType(AttributeType.REFERRED);
            obj.setAttributes(attributes);

            Attributes attributes1 = new Attributes();
            attributes1.setName("name2");
            attributes1.setDataType("Vehicle");
            attributes1.setAttributeType(AttributeType.REFERRED);
            obj.setAttributes(attributes1);


            Attributes attributes2 = new Attributes();
            attributes2.setName("name3");
            attributes2.setDataType("Person");
            attributes2.setAttributeType(AttributeType.REFERRED);
            obj.setAttributes(attributes2);


            List<Attributes> list = List.of(attributes1, attributes2, attributes);

            Map<String, String> collect = list.stream()
                                              .filter(e -> AttributeType.REFERRED.equals(e.getAttributeType()))
                                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Attributes::getDataType,
                                                      Collectors.mapping(Attributes::getName,
                                                              Collectors.joining(","))));

            System.out.println(collect);

}
```

Please note that i used separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I understand , your class EntityObjectDTO need a collection of Attributes (List), which you do not have as you have mentioned , I have changed it like below and got the output , which you needed.

**Output :
{Vehicle=name1,name2, Person=name3}**

```
public @Data class EntityObjectDTO  {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    private List<Attributes> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
public class Attributes {

    private String name;

    private AttributeType attributeType;

    private String dataType;

}

public class Main22 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("******************");
        EntityObjectDTO  obj= new EntityObjectDTO ();

        Attributes attributes = new Attributes();
        attributes.setName("name1");
        attributes.setAttributeType(REFERRED);
        attributes.setDataType("Vehicle");
        obj.getAttributes().add(attributes);

        attributes = new Attributes();
        attributes.setName("name2");
        attributes.setAttributeType(REFERRED);
        attributes.setDataType("Vehicle");
        obj.getAttributes().add(attributes);

        attributes = new Attributes();
        attributes.setName("name3");
        attributes.setAttributeType(REFERRED);
        attributes.setDataType("Person");
        obj.getAttributes().add(attributes);

        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Attributes att : obj.getAttributes()){
            if(myMap.containsKey(att.getDataType())) {
                myMap.put(att.getDataType(), myMap.get(att.getDataType())+","+att.getName());
            }else {
                myMap.put(att.getDataType(), att.getName());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: This also works, but I am preferring java8 Stream api. Anyway Thanks!